# Problems understanding how the modulo operator (%) works in Python

Tags: python

```py
ans=0
while ans<50:
   if ans%10==0:
     ans+=5
   elif ans%5==0:
     ans+=10
   else:
     ans+=15
print(ans)
```

I am terribly sorry to waste your precious time but I cannot get how the value is 55.
I don't understand the flow of the code, so I would like for someone to explain it to me.

Comment: Print `ans` in every branch of conditions and after if-elif-else block and follow numbers. Or use debugger. Do you know what your conditions mean?

Comment: The debugger can answer this, if you are using VS Code you can for example use https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging, for other IDEs there are similar options.

Comment: What does this code have to do with writing titles? Please use the title to describe your problem, don't just give up on writing a good title.

Comment: Another good way to understand code is to write the variables down on a piece of paper. Then pretend you're the computer executing the code.

Comment: Add the print(ans) inside the loop before the if statement. That will tell you the value of each ans after each loop.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator (`%`) in Python internally calls the [`__mod__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__). The purpose of this method is to return the *remainder* of integer divisions, or 0 if no remainder exists.

To give some more tangible examples:

- `5 % 2` => `1` (2 fits into 5 twice, creating 4 and leaving 1)
- `50 % 5` => `0` (50 is evenly divisible by 5)
- `0 % n` => `0` (multiplying anything by 0 yields 0, so 0 divides by everything for all of 0 times)

This also showcases your problem; initializing to 0 means the first modulo check will always pass. Try instead to initialize it to `None` and move the `else` block to a very first `if ans is None:` that *assigns* 15 instead. No need to keep the `else` block beyond the first iteration, as any multiple of 15 is guaranteed to be divisible by 5. Unless of course this is just to model your real problem, in which case keep the else block but still initialize `ans` to `None` and check for that first.

To explain the flow of the code itself:

```py
ans=0
while ans<50:
    # check if ans is an integer multiple of 10. First run: True. Add 5.
    # Now ans is 5 and this check won't pass on the second run
    if ans%10==0:
        ans+=5
    # check if ans is an integer multiple of 5. First run never reaches here.
    # Second run reaches here, adds 10 so the next run is also not a
    # multiple of 10 (5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55)
    elif ans%5==0:
        ans+=10
    else:
        ans+=15
# Print whatever is in ans now (55, always)
print(ans)
```

The change I proposed would still result in an outcome of 55, because it immediately skips to 15, which is still not divisible by 10.

Perhaps also look at [Wikipedia on Modulo operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) for some more info.